# My failing Selenium test works manually

Tags: java, hibernate, selenium

I have a Selenium test which has been working as expected for the past 1 month.
Since last week this one test alone fails 8 times out of 10, when the form is saved, throwing a Hibernate "Transient Object Exception". So it doesn't fail 100% but just around 80-90% of the time. But it fails just at that one point when Save button is clicked.
The developers tell me that they have changed nothing at all in the test server in the last one week.
I tried the same form manually about 10 times and it saves perfectly all 10 times.
Could there be something wrong with my Selenium test ?

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: are you going to post the code?

Comment: Hi @LiamSorsby i did try to post the code but it exceeded the StackOverflow limit for number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

The exception means that the object that is fed to hibernate (I'm guessing a Java representation of the form) is not attached to the hibernate scope at the time of saving/updating.
Given that it works manually and not with Selenium, I'm guessing a race condition.
Something like an update/delete being performed while the matching object is not (yet) attached to the hibernate session.

Selenium is quite a bit faster at clicking then a human ;-)

My best bet would have the programmers look at any (async) calls to the database via hibernate and execution order of those calls and see if there are any race conditions possible (or in this case; where).

Comment: I added a lot of sleep time during each step before clicking the Submit, since that was the only corrective action i could take. After that of course i have no control.

Comment: very well said, Barre.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a wait command? It may be something as simple as trying to select the element a little to early.